# The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter

In my project, I pass data from one widget to another using this code:

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                TranslatorSignUpStep2(transModel: this._translatorModel),
          ),
        );
```

Then I retrive it in the other widget by the code below:

```
class TranslatorSignUpStep2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final TranslatorModel transModel;
  TranslatorSignUpStep2({this.transModel});

  @override
  _TranslatorSignUpStep2State createState() => _TranslatorSignUpStep2State();
}
```

The problem is, in the TranslatorSignUpStep2 class I want to assign the passed-in `transModel` to another variable so I write this code

```
class _TranslatorSignUpStep2State extends State<TranslatorSignUpStep2> {
  TranslatorModel _translatorModel = widget.transModel;
}
```

But it seems like the `widget` can't be used outside the build method so I get error saying
`The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.`. Anyone know how to get over this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this code :

TranslatorSignUpStep2 :

```
    class TranslatorSignUpStep2 extends StatefulWidget {
      final TranslatorModel transModel;
      TranslatorSignUpStep2({this.transModel});

      @override
      _TranslatorSignUpStep2State createState() => _TranslatorSignUpStep2State(this.transModel);
    }
```

TranslatorSignUpStep2 class :

```
  class _TranslatorSignUpStep2State extends State<TranslatorSignUpStep2> {
   _TranslatorSignUpStep2State(TranslatorModel _tempModel ){
    this._translatorModel =_tempModel;
    };
     TranslatorModel _translatorModel ;
    }
```

Answer (score 54):

you can access widget in initState function like this.

```
class _TranslatorSignUpStep2State extends State<TranslatorSignUpStep2> {
  TranslatorModel _translatorModel ;

@override
void initState() {
_translatorModel = widget.transModel;
}

}
```

Comment: I try this, when I `print(widget.transModel)` it's defined but `print(_translatorModel)` is null

Comment: where you call print(_translatorModel) ?

Comment: I've a button on my screen and when I press it, it calls the `print(_translatorModel)`

Comment: You forgot to call super.initState() in initState() override.

Answer (score 37):

Just add the keyword `late` while initializing:

```
class TranslatorSignUpStep2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final TranslatorModel transModel;
  TranslatorSignUpStep2({this.transModel});

  @override
  _TranslatorSignUpStep2State createState() => _TranslatorSignUpStep2State();
}

class _TranslatorSignUpStep2State extends State<TranslatorSignUpStep2> {
  late TranslatorModel _translatorModel = widget.transModel;
}
```

Comment: simple worked solution

Comment: can you please explain why it's not working without late?

Answer (score 3):

Add `static` keyword when innitializing

Answer (score 1):

```
 class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {
      int selectedDays;
     OrderDetails({
        this.range,)};
    
    @override
      _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
    }
    class _OrderDetailsState extends State<OrderDetails> {
    String getRange;
    
    
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    getRange = widget.range;
    }
```

Comment: please mention the cause of the issue and what has to be changed and which pieces were added by you.

Comment: Could you add some explaination, please? And more relation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer was posted by @YAPS. but he did not explain why it works if a late keyword is used.

```
  final TranslatorModel transModel;
  TranslatorSignUpStep2({this.transModel});

  @override
  _TranslatorSignUpStep2State createState() => _TranslatorSignUpStep2State();
}

class _TranslatorSignUpStep2State extends State<TranslatorSignUpStep2> {
  late TranslatorModel _translatorModel = widget.transModel;
}
```

**The explanation is copied from Bard AI**

The reason you need to use the `late` keyword when accessing `widget` in the `_TranslatorSignUpStep2State` class is related to the order of initialization in Dart.

**Without `late`:**

In Dart, fields are initialized before the constructor body is executed. This means that when you access `widget` within the initializer for `_translatorModel`, the `widget` property might not be fully initialized yet, leading to the error message "The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer".

**With `late`:**

The `late` keyword tells Dart that the field will be initialized later in the code, allowing you to access it safely even if its value isn't available yet during field initialization.

Here's a breakdown of what happens with both approaches:

**Without `late`:**

1. `_translatorModel` is declared and its initializer is executed.
2. Within the initializer, you try to access `widget.transModel`, but `widget` itself is not fully initialized yet.
3. This results in the error message because you're trying to access an uninitialized field.

**With `late`:**

1. `_translatorModel` is declared with the `late` keyword, indicating that its value will be assigned later.
2. The constructor body is executed.
3. Within the constructor body, you can safely access `widget` because it has been fully initialized by the time the constructor finishes.
4. Finally, you assign the value of `widget.transModel` to `_translatorModel` after it is guaranteed to be available.

In summary, using `late` ensures that you access the `widget` property only when it's fully initialized, avoiding potential errors and ensuring your code is safe and reliable.