# How to disable send a message to Firestore until the other user has responded

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to have a chat app where if I send the first message, I want to restrict the the message textfield in the bottomNavigationBar so that I need to wait until the other person replies to my message. Any idea how I can manage that bottom part with this code?

Bottom part of the code is where I am trying to put some logic so that instead of the message textfield, user can see  "Please wait for the other person to reply first." message.

```
class PrivateChatMessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String friendId;
  final String friendImage;
  final String friendName;
  PrivateChatMessageScreen({
    required this.friendId,
    required this.friendImage,
    required this.friendName,
  });
bool _first = false;

/*
error here due to widget
final messages = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("messages")
        .doc(widget.friendId)
        .collection("privatemessages");
*/

  @override
  State<PrivateChatMessageScreen> createState() =>
      _PrivateChatMessageScreenState();
}
class _PrivateChatMessageScreenState extends State<PrivateChatMessageScreen> {

/*
or error here due to widget
final messages = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("messages")
        .doc(widget.friendId)
        .collection("privatemessages");
*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUserUid =
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser?.uid ?? '';
    final currentUserName =
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser?.fullname ?? '';
    return Scaffold( 
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("messages")
                    .doc(widget.friendId)
                    .collection("privatemessages")
                    .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)             
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
if (snapshot.data.docs.length == 1 &&                  snapshot.data!.docs.first.get("fromId") !=
                            currentUseruid) {
                      _first = true;
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Please wait until other person replies',
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final textMessage = snapshot.data.docs[index]['text'];
                        final messageid = snapshot.data.docs[index]['id'];
                        final fromId = snapshot.data.docs[index]['fromId'];
                        bool isMe = snapshot.data.docs[index]["fromId"] ==
                            currentUseruid;   
                        return isMe
                            ? GestureDetector(
                                child: SingleMessage(
                                  timestamp: snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      ['timestamp'],
                                  isMe: isMe,
                                  message: snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      ['imageUrl'],
                                  toId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['toId'],
                                  fromId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['fromId'],
                                  messageId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['id'],
                                ))
                            : GestureDetector(
                                child: SingleMessage(
                                  timestamp: snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      ['timestamp'],
                                  type: MessageType.image,
                                  isMe: isMe,
                                  message: snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      ['imageUrl'],
                                  toId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['toId'],
                                  fromId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['fromId'],
                                  messageId: snapshot.data.docs[index]['id'],
                                ),
                              );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      bottomNavigationBar:
          _first
          ? Text('Wait')
          : 
          SafeArea(
        child: MessageTextField(
          user?.uid ?? '',
          widget.friendId,
          widget.friendImage,
          widget.friendName,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsts off, pull this into a field in your `_PrivateChatMessageScreenState` class:

```
final messages = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("messages")
    .doc(widget.friendId)
    .collection("privatemessages")
    .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)             
    .snapshots();
```

And then use that in the `stream` property of your `StreamBuilder`:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: messages
```

This isn't strictly needed for the problem, but will prevent rereading all documents whenever the UI (re)renders. Also see the second example in the Firebase documentation on [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart).

---

With that out of the way, you can now look at the latest document in the latest messages inside the `StreamBuilder`, check who sent it, and only enable the button to send a message when it's not the current user.

```
snapshot.data!.docs[0].get("fromId") != currentUseruid
```

Here `docs[0]` is the most recent document, since you ordered on descending creation date.

Comment: Thanks Frank! That was very helpful Since bottomnavigationbar is outside of the Streambuilder I came up with having a bool in "_PrivateChatMessageScreenState". This works well if I send a message go back to the prior view and come back to the messages view however it doesn't work while streambuilder is on and I am in the message thread. Do you know what I can do to fix that?  @Frank

Comment: I tried to change it to  setState(() {  _first = true  }); but that gave an error.

Comment: My code is updated.

Comment: You can pull the `StreamBuilder` up as far in your widget tree as is needed for both widget to be able to access the data.

Comment: Thanks again Frank but in that case Flutter complains about "widget.friendId" which is why I have been trying to use that _first bool :) Otherwise, I'd love to push it over.

Comment: "Flutter complains about widget.friendId" I don't know what that means, but if you have an error while trying to make this work - include the exact error message and stack trace in the question please.

Comment: Of course Frank. Code updated with the error  "The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression" Let me know if I made an error.

Comment: Search for that error message makes it clear that you need an `initState` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092241/the-instance-member-widget-cant-be-accessed-in-an-initializer

Comment: Thanks @Frank! Your original solution worked with a workaround so I am going to mark this as resolved :)